# What should be the input type for a UDF taking in columns of type - Array of StructType or "null"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Schema of my DataFrame is as follows:

```scala
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- unit1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sum(unit2): string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- max(unit3): string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- unit1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sum(unit2): string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- max(unit3): string (nullable = true)
```

I'm writing a UDF in scala which takes in cols - col2 and col3.
What should be my input type for each of the columns i'm passing to the UDF considering the value of col2 can be **"null"**

```scala
val process_stuff = udf((col2: ???, col3: ??? ) => {
```

So far i've tried this and my other things

```scala
val process_stuff = udf((col2:ArrayType[StructType[StructField]], col3:ArrayType[StructType[StructField]]) => {
```

but it gives me warnings here and there
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your UDF should have the following signature :

```
val process_stuff = udf((col2: Seq[Row], col3: Seq[Row]) => {...})
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Inside the UDF i'm getting type mismatch error when i access unit1 : Says "found: Any , required : String"

Comment: try to replace Seq[Row] to Seq[String] it should work.